# Flash reference error: "Cannot create property __id0_ on MyMovieClip"

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm using Flash Builder as the main flash dev tool, and use Flash as assets creating tool.
Basically this works fine, but one day I made a 3D tween in Flash timeline, and then link the asset "MyMovieClip" with my actionscript code, like this:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    [Embed(source="somefile.swf", symbol="MyMovieClip")]
    public class MyMovieClip extends MovieClip
    {
        public function MyMovieClip()
        {
            super();
        }
    }
}
```

Then this Error came up: "Error #1056: Cannot create property __id0_ on MyMovieClip".
I'm sure there's no "__id0_" in my fla file.

So I deleted the 3D tween animation layer and re-published the fla file, no Error encountered.

Any clues? Is that impossible to make a movieclip asset with 3D timeline animation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your `MyMovieClip` class a dynamic class:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    [Embed(source="somefile.swf", symbol="MyMovieClip")]
    public dynamic class MyMovieClip extends MovieClip
    {
        public function MyMovieClip()
        {
            super();
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you may have a conflict with an instance on your timeline and property within the somefile.swf movie clip.